# Scala: system commands to a python script with arguments

Tags: python, scala

So I am sending this system command in Scala:

```
val command = "python other/evaluateAnswers.py 'chemistry earth' 'the chemistry of the world in champaign' 'the chemistry of the computer science world'"
```

command.!!

Here is a simplified version of my python code:

```
def main(argv):
    # example run:
    print(argv)
    # do stuff here ... 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

If I run this directly inside terminal:

```
daniel$ python other/evaluateAnswers.py 'chemistry earth' 'the chemistry of the world in champaign' 'the chemistry of the computer science world'
```

Here is the result of `print(argv)` in my python code:

```
['chemistry earth', 'the chemistry of the world in champaign', 'the chemistry of the computer science world']
```

which is correct.

While if I run this from scala via `command.!!` I'd get the following in the output of `print(argv)`:

```
["'chemistry", "earth'", "'the", 'chemistry', 'of', 'the', 'world', 'in', "champaign'", "'the", 'chemistry', 'of', 'the', 'computer', 'science', "world'"]
```

which is incorrect splitting.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: have you tried escaping the spaces: `val command = "python other/evaluateAnswers.py 'chemistry\ earth' 'the\ chemistry\ of\ the\ world\ in\ champaign' 'the chemistry\ of\ the\ computer\ science\ world'"`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it gives me `invalid escape character` compile error.

Answer (score 2):

Manually splitting my scala command did the trick:

```
val command = Seq("python", "other/evaluateAnswers.py", "'chemistry earth'", "'the chemistry of the world in champaign'", "'the chemistry of the computer science world'")
command.!!
```